# how to get the content of other website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small html trying to get the content of other website using javascript. Please help to see where the problem is:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function displayData() {
            $.get('http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt', function(responseText) {
                alert(responseText);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <button type="button" id="btnDisplay" onclick="displayData()">Go</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the error in the console?

Comment: If you open your browser console it will tell you why

Comment: thanks. I saw 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' in the console

Comment: there is your answer

Comment: is there any solution? I don't have control over the server side, by the way